# TypeScript and ReactJS - How to define return type for useContext(...)

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-typescript

How to define return type of this function with typescript?

```
export const useCorporateContext = (): "what should be added here as return type" => {
    return useContext(CorporateContext);
};
```

I am asking this because when I run "npm build" command, I receive warning message in console:

> Warning: Missing return type on function.

Comment: It would be whatever type you used for the value of the context.  If you have Context<T> then useContext returns T.